# creating PKs for existing tables - altering column constraints

Tags: db2

I am quite new to DB2, so I googled around how to ask questions correctly and so I hope I can provide all necessary information.

I have an existing table A1230922.CALSONW with several (195) columns but no primary key. Now I want to connect an ORM that needs a primary key, I guess for row identification.

Googling brought me the result to use the following queries:

- add a column with NOT NULL, and DEFAULT 0 (works fine):

  ALTER TABLE tablename ADD COLUMN orm_id INTEGER NOT NULL WITH DEFAULT 0;
- add automatic increasing key values (does not work, as it is not compatible with column):

  ALTER TABLE tablename ALTER COLUMN orm_id SET GENERATED BY DEFAULT AS IDENTITY;

I only have German error messages (and I cannot change the interface language), saying that the attributes are not compatible with the existing column.

When I try to remove the default 0, or the NOT NULL, I get the error message (translated by myself):

```
ALTER table A1230922.CALSONW alter column orm_id DROP NOT NULL
```

An error occurred during the implicit system action "3". The returned information conaint the SQLCODE "-421", the SQLSTATE "42826", and the message token "[...] full documentation.

The docs for this SQLCODE and SQLSTATE say:

*Short Description: THE OPERANDS OF A UNION OR UNION ALL DO NOT HAVE THE SAME NUMBER OF COLUMNS
The operands of a UNION or UNION ALL must have the same number of columns. System action: The statement cannot be executed. Programmer response: Correct the SQL statement so that there are exactly the same number of columns in each operand.*

Obviously, I am not doing anything with UNION in this context.

Next steps would be to REORG TABLE, SET orm_id = DEFAULT, and ADD CONSTRAINT pk PRIMARY KEY(orm_id).

Version information:

Client: Win 7, 32 Bit, DB2 code release"SQL09075", "08060107".

Version: "DB2 v9.7.500.702", "s111017", "IP23286", FixPak "5".

Server: Win XP (yes, development only), exactly same version

Comment: I think you want either a `Sequence` or an `Identity` (the link is not for the Windows DB2 but the syntax is probably the same): http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/db2luw/v9r7/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.ibm.db2.luw.admin.dbobj.doc%2Fdoc%2Fc0007010.html

Comment: So, this might work: `ALTER TABLE A1230922.CALSONW ADD COLUMN orm_id INT NOT NULL GENERATED ALWAYS AS IDENTITY START WITH 1 INCREMENT BY 1;`

Comment: @ypercube Why would you say that the DB2 LUW (Linux,Unix,Windows) link would not apply to Windows?

Comment: @WarrenT My bad, misread the titles.

Comment: @WarrennT Do you have any insight on why that `ALTER COLUMN` fails? Is it because of the previous properties (`NOT NULL` and/or `WITH DEFAULT 0`) of the column that do not allow the `GENERATED AS IDENTITY` to succeed?

Comment: @ypercube Using your proposed statement I get the error message: SQL0104N "BEGIN-OF-STATEMENT" is followed by unexpected "ALTER TABLE A1230922.CALSONW ADD C". Possible tokens: "<alter_sequence>". I am using the db2 command editor, by the way.

Comment: Okay, more information here: I CAN create a new table with col3 INT NOT NULL GENERATED ALWAYS AS IDENTITY(START WITH 0, INCREMENT BY 1), but altering an existing table and adding an identity column does not work.

Comment: Then I guess WarrenT's answer is right. the problem is the existing `DEFAULT 0` constraint conflicting with the `GENERATED AS DEFAULT`. Try to drop that first and then alter the column.

Answer (score 2):

My expertise is on DB2 for i, not really LUW. That said, I will still offer my thoughts.

I don't think you want your ID field to have a default of zero and say GENERATED BY DEFAULT.

Since this column is giving you so much trouble and is one you added, I might be tempted to drop it, and start from scratch, if practical.

I believe the commonly recommended definition for this field would be

```
ALTER TABLE tablename 
  ADD COLUMN orm_id   INTEGER   NOT NULL
                                GENERATED ALWAYS AS IDENTITY
                                CONSTRAINT tablename_pk PRIMARY KEY;
```

But someone wiser may adjust this advice.